# Divide desktop into areas and windows resize and snap to them

Tags: linux, gnome, desktop, window-manager

I would really like to have my desktop divided into the following

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |-------|
|       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |-------|
|       |       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

so when I drag a window into one of the areas the window would resize and snap to it.

Or if this is easier?

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I use Fedora/Gnome if that makes a difference.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://i3wm.org/ is not exactly what you are asking for, but I suspect it is really what you want.